# MathML - left subscript and superscript

Tags: mathml, subscript, superscript

How to write left subscript and superscript preserving correct syntax of MathML? I mean something like this:

[image: left sub- and superscript]

Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<mmultiscripts>` - see http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter3.html#presm.mmultiscripts for details. In your case, it's:

```
<mmultiscripts>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mprescripts/> <mi>c</mi> <mi>b</mi>
</mmultiscripts>
```